# Proving the trigonometric identity $\frac{1}{\csc A- \cot A} - \frac{1}{\sin A} = + \frac{1}{\sin A} - \frac{1}{\csc A+ \cot A}$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\frac{1}{\csc A- \cot A} - \frac{1}{\sin A} = + \frac{1}{\sin A} - \frac{1}{\csc A+ \cot A}$$

How have I solved it so far :

1. expanded both the expression(LHS & RHS) completely into sin,cos terms and equated both LHS & RHS with cotA=cotA.

When you take a first look at the Q. It looks impossible. Then , it confuses me onto where to start from I.e ( which trigonometric ratio to even expand ! ) since the major difference in both the equation is like arithmetic signs in the LHS and RHS just reversed. It would be very grateful if you could help with me with this Q + also share your thoughts you are having while solving the Q.

Also , do you think that this Q has some property ? Like what the equation shown up is like something which will be true for every equation ? Even in case of arithmetic numbers ? What do you think ? To simplify what I mean here is that do you think

$\frac{1}{\csc-o} - \frac{1}{s} = + \frac{1}{s} -$ $\frac{1}{\csc+o}$ is like some formula.

Comment: What's the issue? You showed that the LHS and RHS are both $\cot A$, so it's proved.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 That’s a really long way. I have to solve both of them for this.

Comment: You can do that in short by mutliplying the fractions by their conjugates _e.g._ $$\dfrac{1}{\csc x-\cot x}\cdot\dfrac{\csc x+\cot x}{\csc x+\cot x}=\csc x + \cot x$$From here, the task of simplifying gets simplified :)

Comment: @MathGenius: Please try to avoid using MathJax in titles as much as possible, as they are not browseable. (A suitable title here could be "proving a trigonometric identity".) You could have edited the math in the post, which would be very helpful!

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Cmon , some people say to write MathJax in title and some say don’t. Really man. You’re first one to say no MathJax in title to me actually. But ok. I’ll do that next time.

Comment: Need not worry about that now, did you see my comment on your question?

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Yes. Thats also a nice way. Also , what were your thoughts before jumping onto this Q.

Comment: It is a common technique because the Pythagorean identity $\csc^2(x)-\cot^2(x)=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\csc A-\cot A$ and $\csc A+\cot A$ are reciprocal of each other. The given expression is

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{\csc A-\cot A} - \frac{1}{\sin A} =  \frac{1}{\sin A} -\frac{1}{\csc A+\cot A}$

$\implies(\csc A+\cot A) -\csc A =\csc A - (\csc A -\cot A )$

$\implies \cot A =\cot A $ which is true

Comment: Is this reciprocal property that you have used . Is it used in all the trigonometry expression or only some ?

Comment: @S.M.T properties are always valid and it will not be right to call it a property, better word would be _identity_ i.e. $\csc A-\cot A =\frac{1}{\csc A +\cot A }$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Rearrange terms to get $$\frac{1}{\csc A-\cot A}+\frac{1}{\csc A+\cot A}=\frac{2}{\sin A}$$ Simplifying L.H.S. is much easier than before.